# Android IntentService Killed After Startup During Long Idle Periods

Tags: android, service, intentservice

After my phone has been idle for several hours, usually about 8, the IntentService scheduled will start but never finish.  I have had the same problem using a Service and START_REDELIVER_INTENT.  It seems to work fine when the phone is in use or has recently been in use.

The snippet of code not completing is the dailyReset.  The first notification goes off so I know that it at least made it there before terminating.

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
static final public String REFRESH_INTENT = "rf";

public AlarmService() {super("AlarmService");}

public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
    broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String message = bundle.getString("alarm");
    if(message.equals("dosesTakenResetAlarm")){
        scheduledReminder(bundle.getInt("code"), "RESET", getApplicationContext());
        dailyReset(getApplicationContext());
        scheduledReminder(bundle.getInt("code")+1, "FINISH", getApplicationContext());
    }
    else if(message.equals("scheduledReminder")){
        scheduledReminder(bundle.getInt("code"), bundle.getString("name"), getApplicationContext());
    }
    WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void dailyReset(Context context){
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(context);
    AlarmCreator ac = new AlarmCreator();
    String saveString = "";
    int start = 0;
    int medNum = 0;
    fw.fp.onloadString(fw.readFromFile());
    if(fw.fp.hasNext()){start = fw.readEntry(medNum).position1;}
    while(fw.fp.hasNext()){
        SaveData mv = fw.readEntry(medNum);
        fw.fp.onloadMedString(mv.data);
        String name = fw.fp.nextMedVariable();
        String doses = fw.fp.nextMedVariable();
        String frequency = fw.fp.nextMedVariable();
        String frequencyS = fw.fp.nextMedVariable();
        String reminders = fw.fp.nextMedVariable();
        String dosesT = fw.fp.nextMedVariable();
        frequencyS = ""+(Integer.parseInt(frequencyS)-1);
        if(Integer.parseInt(frequencyS) < 0){
            frequencyS = ""+(Integer.parseInt(frequency)-1);
        }
        //fw.replaceEntry(fw.fp.buildMedSaveString(name, doses, frequency, frequencyS, reminders, "0"), mv.position1, mv.position2);
        saveString += fw.fp.buildMedSaveString(name, doses, frequency, frequencyS, reminders, "0");
        if(frequencyS.equals("0")){
            fw.fp.onloadReminderString(reminders);
            int reminderNum = 0;
            while(fw.fp.hasNextReminder()){
                ReminderData temp = fw.fp.nextReminder();
                if(temp.half.equals("1")){
                    temp.hour = ""+(Integer.parseInt(temp.hour)+12);
                }
                ac.setAlarm(Integer.parseInt(temp.hour), Integer.parseInt(temp.minute), 0, ac.buildAlarmCode(medNum, reminderNum), name);
                reminderNum++;
            }
        }
        medNum++;
        fw.fp.nextMedication();
    }
    if(medNum > 0){
        fw.replaceEntry(saveString, start, fw.readFromFile().length());
        System.out.println(fw.readFromFile());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(REFRESH_INTENT);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void scheduledReminder(int code, String n, Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nicon)
                    .setContentTitle("Pillbud Reminder")
                    .setContentText("Take a dosage of "+n+".  "+code);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    mBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(code, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: what is `FileWriter#readEntry` ?

Comment: The save file's information are separated into entries.  The readEntry method just reads the number specified and returns a SaveData class containing the save String and where it starts and ends.

Comment: so it blocks, or `hasNext`

Comment: No, readEntry just reads it, it doesn't increment.  nextMedication increments and then turns hasNext to false if there is nothing more.  Originally I was using nextMedication to just return the String but I made the readEntry method because occasionally I need more information.  The nextMedVariable displays how it functions basically.

Comment: without any code, its hard to tell anything, no one is an oracle...

Comment: I don't believe that code is a problem.  As I've said the code runs fine while it's awake or recently has been awake.   It seems more likely that the device runs out of memory kills the service or for some reason the cpu  turns off despite the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.